# error when trying to compile test javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, compiler-errors, compilation

I am currently looking for a GUI framework that is both modern and has a decent webviewer.
When I was lookig, I found the JavaFX Framework. As of JDK11 it is the case that JavaFX is not delievered with the JDK anymore, so I installed the .jar manually. I also kept in mind to edit the VM options as suggested in the IntelliJ tutorial.
[VM options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGTO.jpg)
Now, I should be ready to compile, but I still get the following error message. Does anyone know why this error message is showing?
If it is because I am using OpenJDK 11, is there any option to get a JavaFX version that is compatible with OpenJDK11? (I am not allowed to upgrade)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac9DL.png)

Comment: JavaFX 11-14 is compatible with Java 11+. Did you download the correct JavaFX SDK for your platform? JavaFX has native code which is platform-specific.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the JavaFX Windows SDK for my Windows PC.

Comment: Did you leave the layout of the SDK intact (e.g. the DLL files are in the `bin` directory)?

Comment: You should follow the official documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ This has worked for me and others too. You also said "I installed the .jar manually". One .jar is not enough.

Comment: @mipa I do not see the difference with what I was doing (setting VM options) in the IntelliJ section? And yes, I imported everything (all jars) from the lib directory. I was unprecise in my formulation here, sorry.

Comment: @slaw Yes, I left everything the same in the JDK directory.

Comment: You have an UnsatisfiedLinkError which means that there is still something missing in your setup.

Comment: I can only again assure that I imported everything and set every vm option, that is mentioned. (https://imgur.com/a/RvsjOT9)

Answer (score 0):

whitin yout installation of JavaFX is a folder called bin. it has some dll files needed in your JavaFX project. If you just added the jars into the classpath of your project without changing their locations it should find the dlls automatically.

another way to work this out is to copy those dlls and paste them into the bin folder in your jdk installation

Comment: Ok, thanks to this information I found out that probably the PC at the company is blocking the dlls since, after inserting them manually, the whole jdk did not work anymore. The problem is that we trainees only have limited rights and we can only use the pre-installed OpenJDK 11 and nothing else.